# AlertDialog RecyclerView hides Ok/Cancel buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I want to display a list of items in alert dialog using a custom view. If there are a few items the OK button is shown, adding more items makes the dialog window bigger until only the list is visible.
This is the custom view I set in the dialog, it has only the list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:clipToPadding="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the C# code, (I think it's easy to read in java/kotlin)

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.Activity)
        .SetPositiveButton("OK", (obj, ev) => { });
        View dialogView = (View)this.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog, null);
        builder.SetView(dialogView);
        RecyclerView rv = dialogView.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerview);
        var mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this.Activity, 4);
        rv.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter ();
        rv.SetAdapter(adapter);
        var items = new List<string>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            items.Add(i.ToString());
        adapter.SetItems(items);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.Create();
        dialog.Show();
```

How can I make the Recyclerview not covering the OK button?
Thank You

Comment: don't use 'setPositiveButton("OK"), instead make the 'OK' button inside your custom layout and use its click listener. It will give you full control on your ui.

Comment: @D_Alpha Thanks, I added a button after RecyclerView but it's not shown when I add more items